# How to remove the pop-up that appears on the tinyMCE rich text editor (See image)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

[image]

This is the initilization script:

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: '.jsContentTextBox',
                plugins: 'print preview paste importcss searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen link table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount textpattern noneditable help charmap quickbars',
                menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
                toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | link anchor | ltr rtl',
                toolbar_sticky: true,
                content_css: [
                    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i'
                ],
                importcss_append: true,
                height: $("input[id*='EditorHeightHiddenField']").val(),
                quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote  quicktable',
                noneditable_noneditable_class: "mceNonEditable",
                toolbar_drawer: 'sliding',
                contextmenu: "link table",
            });
```

I have tried a few combinations in the above script to try and turn off the pop-up, but that hasn't worked. I have used the full featured: non-premium plugins version of the init script at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/ as the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is part of the `quickbars` plugin: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/quickbars

There are two types of quick bars and if you want either of them to not appear you need to set them to an empty string like this:

```
quickbars_insert_toolbar: '',
quickbars_selection_toolbar: '',
```

For example this keeps the selection toolbar but not the insert toolbar.

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Aahaab/1

Comment: Thanks. quickbars_insert_toolbar: '', did the trick. I did not know it was referred to as quickbar!