# Disable popup tools tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to disable this popup :

[image]

But I don't know how to do it and the tinymce documentation doesn't help me.
It only happens when I click in a white line.

This is the code that I use to start the plugin:

```
tinymce.init({
  force_br_newlines : true,
  selector:'#'+id,
  content_style: 'div { margin: 10px; border: 5px solid red; padding: 3px; }',
  plugins: ['autolink','autoresize','codesample','link','lists', 'advlist','media','table','image','quickbars','codesample',
                'print','textpattern','emoticons','help','directionality', 'hr', 'quickbars', 'searchreplace', 'wordcount','quickbars', 'code'],
  toolbar: ' undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | aling | numlist bullist | image link print | hr | searchreplace wordcount | code'
                                
            });
```

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015728/how-to-remove-the-pop-up-that-appears-on-the-tinymce-rich-text-editor-see-image#answer-60023632

Comment: Yes, quickbars_insert_toolbar: '' is the solution